# HP Fortify: How define new issue alert

Tags: alert, fortify

How do i define an alert on HP Fortify SSC which will go off only if new issues have been discovered or if the number if issues have increased since the last scan.

I can define an alert with a static number of issues but that would need to be manually updated everytime the number of alerts changes, which I would like to avoid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok. After much craziness, I believe I have found a solution to this problem. This works in SSC 4.00. Perhaps others can confirm for other version.

## Create the Alert

1. Login to Fortify SSC
2. Click the "Administration" tab.
3. Click "Alert Definitions".
4. Click "Add".
5. Enter a name, such as "New Issues".
6. For type, select "Variable".
7. For alert when, enter "NEWIssues > 0".
8. Add the relevant projects to the scope.
9. Click "Save".

## Make Sure to Receive Emails

1. Login to Fortify SSC.
2. Click "Preferences" (top-right corner).
3. Select the "Alert Notifications" tab.
4. Make sure "Email Alert Notifications" is selected.
5. Click "Save".